Compactness criterion in the Skorokhod space $\mathbb D([0,T],E)$ with separable $E$
For a metric space $(E,d)$, we define the Skorokhod space $\mathbb D([0,T],E)$ as being the set of all functions from $[0,T]$ to $E$ which are right-continuous and with left limits.
In the case where $E$ is equipped with a Polish topology, then there is an explicit characterization of relatively compact sets in $\mathbb D([0,T],E)$, see for instance Ethier-Kurtz, Theorem $6.3$ page $123$. It states that a set $A\subset\mathbb D([0,T],E)$ is relatively compact if and only if :
$1)$ $\{x(t) : x\in A, t\in[0,T]\}$ is relatively compact in $E$.
$2)$ $\underset{\delta\rightarrow0}\lim\underset{x\in A}\sup w'_\delta(x)=0$, where we define $w'_\delta(x):=\underset{0\le t\le1-\delta}\sup\underset{u,s\in[t,t+\delta]}\sup\text{ }d(x(u),x(s))$
Do such characterizations exist when we no longer suppose that $E$ is equipped with a Polish topology? For instance, if we only suppose that the topology on $E$ is separable, can we give a similar characterization of compactness in $\mathbb D([0,T],E)$?
Maybe if we consider $(\hat E,\hat d)$ as the completion of $(E,d)$, we can use the preceding characterization to describe the relatively compact sets of $\mathbb D([0,T],\hat E)$, and thus deduce those of $\mathbb D([0,T],E)$, but I'm not sure how that would work or how explicit it would be.
